# Require assistance in writing a mysql query for the problem below

Tags: mysql

I need help writing a query to display hotel id, hotel name and hotel type of 
hotels which have not taken any orders in the month of 'MAY 19'. Sort the result based on hotel id in ascending order.

Assume we have two table hotel_details and orders.

I have tried the following code

`select hotel_id,hotel_name,hotel_type from hotel_details
natural join orders
where order_id is null and monthname(order_date)="May"
group by(hotel_id);`

Comment: What have you tried? What trouble are you having? DBA and SO aren't free coding/SQLing services, they are to help if you have having trouble, and have put effort into solving the problems. Including `SHOW CREATE TABLE hotel_details` (and `orders`) and the SQL have tried would be most appreciated.

Comment: `select hotel_id,hotel_name,hotel_type from hotel_details
natural join orders
where order_id is null and monthname(order_date)="May"
group by(hotel_id);`

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! Please put the SQL that you have tried into the text of the question (use the edit link - you can always edit your own posts). Is this homework? Homework is **not** off-topic here, but we have two requirements for answering - 1) that you're open and honest about it being homework and 2) that you have at least tried something yourself.

Comment: Any May?  Consider `LEFT(order_date, 7) = '2019-05'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where on the right track;

natural joins are horrible because a) if there is no table structure, you can't read what they say (hence I'm guessing as the join critiera) b) people change the table structure in the future, and then the query is different.

A `left join` is required to match hotels where there is no orders. Your `where order_id is null` could never be true on the same row as `monthname(order_date)="May"` (if `order_id` is null, then `order_date` must be also).

As a `left join` criteria however, if there is no match, the `order` side of the result set is empty. Because of this properties we apply the month criteria here.

Grouping by `hotel_id` was correct.

Finally using `having` is a criteria based after the aggregation. As `NULL` isn't counted, the total count for the month must be 0.

```
select hotel_id,hotel_name,hotel_type
from hotel_details
left join orders
   on hotel_details.hotel_id = orders.hotel_id
   and monthname(order_date)="May"
group by hotel_id
having count(orders.order_id) = 0
order by hotel_id
```

Comment: The order by is missing.

Comment: i get an error hotel_id in field list is ambiguous

Comment: I'm going to leave it to you to work that bit out. Both tables have `hotel_id`, however because of `left join`, the `order`'s `hotel_id` might be null

Comment: thank you..let me work on it :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. If something else already did your job please share.

```
select distinct 
  hotel_details.hotel_id, 
  hotel_details.hotel_name, 
  hotel_details.hotel_type 
from hotel_details inner join orders 
    on hotel_details.hotel_id=orders.hotel_id 
where (
    month(order_date)=05 
    and month(order_date)=06
      ) 
group by (hotel_id)
```

Comment: Thanks you and i also did that using the following code suggested by my friend 
   `select distinct hotel_id,hotel_name,hotel_type from hotel_details
    natural join orders
    where hotel_id<> all(select hotel_id from orders where month(order_date)=5)order by hotel_id;`